# snmpwalk in python subprocess

Tags: python, python-2.7, net-snmp

It works in my `Bash` shell:

```
$ snmpwalk -V
NET-SNMP version: 5.7.2.1
```

But when I try to execute the exact same command via python `subprocess`:

```
In [1]: from subprocess import check_output, STDOUT

In [2]: print check_output(["snmpwalk", "-V"], stderr=STDOUT, shell=True)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CalledProcessError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-9886fda8a591> in <module>()
----> 1 print check_output(["snmpwalk", "-V"], stderr=STDOUT, shell=True)

/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.pyc in check_output(*popenargs, **kwargs)
    571         if cmd is None:
    572             cmd = popenargs[0]
--> 573         raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
    574     return output
    575 

CalledProcessError: Command '['snmpwalk', '-V']' returned non-zero exit status 1

In [3]: print check_output(["/usr/bin/snmpwalk", "-V"], stderr=STDOUT, shell=True)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CalledProcessError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-25c11cea9013> in <module>()
----> 1 print check_output(["/usr/bin/snmpwalk", "-V"], stderr=STDOUT, shell=True)

/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.pyc in check_output(*popenargs, **kwargs)
    571         if cmd is None:
    572             cmd = popenargs[0]
--> 573         raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
    574     return output
    575 

CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/snmpwalk', '-V']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Any ideas what's wrong here?

Comment: You should either set `shell=False` or use command `snmpwalk -V` (so not in a list)

Comment: @brm Perfect, thank you.